# Writing Pulp Optimization function using Dataframe as input

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am having trouble writing a pulp optimization problem using the below dataframe and constraints:

```
    seniority  target  morning_in  morning_out  afternoon_in  afternoon_out

0      3        6      NaN         08:50          14:30         NaN
1      4        6      NaN         08:20          15:20         NaN 
2      1        6      NaN         08:40          13:00         NaN
```

Constraints:

1. Hours have to be the same for both rows in the columns 'morning_in' and 'afternoon_out'
2. (morning_out - morning_in) + (afternoon_out - afternoon_in) must be equal to 'target'
3. If seniority == 1 then morning_in is between 07:00 - 08:00, if seniority == 3 then morning_in between 06:30 - 07:30, if seniority == 4 then morning_in between 06:00 - 07:00
4. Afternoon_out is between 16:00 and 19:00

I cannot manage to write the pulp function without using a for loop.

Comment: Then show your `for` loop.

Comment: If `afternoon_out` is all NaN, how could you define constant 2?